# Code::Blocks - warnings disappear when running program

Tags: warnings, compiler-warnings, codeblocks, gcc-warning

I'm using Code::Blocks 10.05 (currently on Windows).
When I run the program (Ctrl + F10), all the warnings in the build log disappear, so the first line is "Checking for existence...".
So when I build & run (F9), it's not possible to read the warnings, because they're only visible for a few seconds.

Where is the setting to change that?

Comment: I looked and was not able to find an answer in the IDE itself or in the documentation.  You may want to ask at [their forum](http://forums.codeblocks.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply use the **Build** command for your project without running it. Shortcut for this is Ctrl + F9. That way you get to keep your build log.